# OpenMP loop runs code slower than serial loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm running this neat little gravity simulation and in serial execution it takes a little more than 4 minutes, when i parallelize one loop inside a it increases to about 7 minutes and if i try parallelizing more loops it increases to more than 20 minutes. I'm posting a slightly shortened version without some initializations but I think they don't matter. I'm posting the 7 minute version however with some comments where i wanted to add parallelization to loops. Thank you for helping me with my messy code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define numb 1000
int main(){
  double pos[numb][3],a[numb][3],a_local[3],v[numb][3];
  memset(v, 0.0, numb*3*sizeof(double));
  double richtung[3];
  double t,deltat=0.0,r12 = 0.0,endt=10.;
  unsigned seed;
  int tcount=0;
  #pragma omp parallel private(seed) shared(pos)
  {
    seed = 25235 + 16*omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp for 
    for(int i=0;i<numb;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        pos[i][j] = (double) (rand_r(&seed) % 100000 - 50000);
      }
    }
  }
  for(t=0.;t<endt;t+=deltat){
    printf("\r%le", t);
    tcount++;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(pos,v)
    for(int id=0; id<numb; id++){
      for(int l=0;l<3;l++){
        pos[id][l] = pos[id][l]+(0.5*deltat*v[id][l]);
        v[id][l] = v[id][l]+a[id][l]*(deltat);
      }
    }
    memset(a, 0.0, numb*3*sizeof(double));
    memset(a_local, 0.0, 3*sizeof(double));
    #pragma omp parallel for private(r12,richtung) shared(a,pos)
    for(int id=0; id <numb; ++id){
      for(int id2=0; id2<id; id2++){
        for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
          r12 += sqrt((pos[id][k]-pos[id2][k])*(pos[id][k]-pos[id2][k]));
        }
        for(int k=0; k<3;k++){
          richtung[k] = (-1.e10)*(pos[id][k]-pos[id2][k])/r12;
          a[id][k] += richtung[k]/(((r12)*(r12)));
          a_local[k] += (-1.0)*richtung[k]/(((r12)*(r12)));
          #pragma omp critical
          {
            a[id2][k] += a_local[k];
          }
        }
        r12=0.0;
      }
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(pos)
    for(int id =0; id<numb; id++){
      for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
        pos[id][k] = pos[id][k]+(0.5*deltat*v[id][k]);
      }
    }
    deltat= 0.01;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using 
    `g++ -fopenmp -o test_grav test_grav.c` 
to compile the code and I'm measuring time in the shell just by 
    `time ./test_grav`. 
When I used 
    `get_numb_threads()` 
to get the number of threads it displayed 4. `top` also shows more than 300% (sometimes ~380%) cpu usage. Interesting little fact if I start the parallel region before the time-loop (meaning the most outer for-loop) and without any actual `#pragma omp for` it is equivalent to making one parallel region for every major (the three second to most outer loops) loop. So I think it is an optimization thing, but I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

**Edit:** I made the example verifiable and lowered numbers like `numb` to make it better testable but the problem still occurs. Even when I remove the critical region as suggested by TheQuantumPhysicist, just not as severely.

Comment: The critical section looks evil. Can't you just rerun the loop and keep that critical section outside with no parallelization?

Comment: The critical region solves a race-condition with my acceleration `a[id2][0,1,2]` like a reduction onto an array. And i do need the id2 loop so I'm writing to the right forces int a.

Comment: Where is `richtung` defined? It makes a big difference if it's an array or a pointer. If it's an array then OpenMP will make private arrays for each thread (like you want). If it's a pointer then you only get a private pointer for each thread.  Have you checked that the parallel version gets the same answer? You do ` r12=0.0;` at the end of your loop so the initial value of `r12` is undefined for each thread.

Comment: How big is `numb`. You need to do enough work to overcome the OpenMP overhead.

Comment: @Haemiltoen I understand, but you probably didn't understand my alternative solution. Just create another loop *outside that parallelized loop* and don't use OpenMP there. Would that work for you? If it does, it'll definitely be much better than whatever you have there. Critical sections mean you're using locking and mutexes, which by definition will slow down your code.

Comment: @Z boson `r12` is initialized as `double r12=0.0;` so it should have initial value `0.0`. numb is `1000`. and initialized `richtung` as `static double richtung[3]` which is fine for the serial execution but dumb for parallel. And replaced it and now my code runs in 3 minutes. And thank you very much. I feel dumb...

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist that is a great idea and I'll try that out I didn't think clearly of how to implement the "outside the loop" clearly. However both versions are "slower" than what i'd imagine it beeing in an optimal execution. I'll try to see which is actually faster.

Comment: @Haemiltoen I added a solution with what I imagine it should look like as an answer. Take a look there.

Comment: Can you please make that example verifiable (see [mcve])? That way a proper answer with specific performance insights and results can be created. What system did you run it on (CPU, Memory configuration). Also you should use at least `-O3` for performance related results.

Comment: I strongly believe there are much better ways to deal with this than the current accepted answer suggests, but I don't like to give an answer without being able to test if it actually performs correct and well, hence my previous request for a verifiable example.

Comment: I'll try to write it up as soon as possible.

Comment: @Zulan I changed the code, so you can have another look at it. thank you.

Comment: Your code is actually very wrong, both serial and parallel. In the first inner loop, you use uninitialized values of `k` and `l=3` for the last one. You are also missing many `private` declarations for inner loop variables. Use `for(int ..=0;..)` loops **everywhere** to avoid those issues. Also, measure with `-O3` and tell us your system specifications. Instead of reducing `numb`, reduce `endt` as this keeps the compute/overhead ratio.

Comment: What is the meaning of writing to `a` when it's value is `memset` right before it is used again? One could just optimize away the entire middle loop. Also there are more race conditions on `a` and `a_local`. You should also declare `r12` and `richtung[k]` locally.

Comment: Thank you very much. The `memset`'s have to be after the new calculation of the `pos` and `v`, of course to reset the calculation of `a` so that it can be calculated using only new `pos`. I thought that `#pragma omp parallel for` takes the following `for`-loop with its iterator and devides it among threads with a default chunksize. Am I misunderstanding that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that critical section is the cause of the problem. Consider taking all critical sections outside the parallelized loop and running them after the parallelization is over.

Try this:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,pos)
{
#pragma omp for private(id2,k,r12,richtung,a_local) 
for(id=0; id <numb; ++id){
    for(id2=0; id2<id; id2++){
        for(k=0;k<3;k++){
            r12 += sqrt((pos[id][k]-pos[id2][k])*(pos[id][k]-pos[id2][k]));
        }
        for(k =0; k<3;k++){
            richtung[k] = (-1.e10)*(pos[id][k]-pos[id2][k])/r12;
            a[id][k] += richtung[k]/(((r12)*(r12))+epsilon);
            a_local[k]+= richtung[k]/(((r12)*(r12))+epsilon)*(-1.0);
        }
    }
}
}
for(id=0; id <numb; ++id){
    for(id2=0; id2<id; id2++){
        for(k=0;k<3;k++){
            a[id2][k] += a_local[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Critical sections will lead to locking and blocking. If you can keep these sections linear, you'll win a lot in performance.

Notice that I'm talking about a syntactic solution, which I don't know whether it works for your case. But to be clear: If every point in your series depends on the next one, then parallelizing is not a solution for you; at least simple parallelization using OpenMP.

Comment: yes, this will solve the critical section problem just instead of `a_local[k]` i'll have to use `a[id][k]*(-1.0)` and it'll mean that i run two loops with `(1000^2 -1000)/2` iterations instead of one.

Comment: @Haemiltoen Then this is definitely faster. Do it, and see what happens. Keep in mind the number of iterations doesn't really matter. What matters is what you do inside the loop.

Comment: @TheQuantimPhysicist Well now it runs faster than with the critical region but with 5 minutes still 1minute slower than in serial. But i can't parallelize the second loop or I'll get a race-condition which i would have to solve via some sort of critical region or reduction to an array which should be the same. But thank you for your help I think I learned a few thing about OpenMP.

Comment: @Haemiltoen You're welcome. If this issue is closed, select the answer above through the check mark.

Comment: @Haemiltoen why did you remove the check mark? What's going on?

Comment: @TheQuantimPhysicist I changed the code so that it can be tested by other people more easily and the problem is still there even without the critical section, just not that severely. Your answer helps but as Zulan said, there "should be a better way to deal with this". If i think about it naively, at each loop the work should be separated and even if it doesn't go twice as fast it should at least go a little faster than serial execution. Unless the implicit barriers do something strange.